# Need for definite article in plurals

Tags: definite-article

Sometimes, in German, I want to describe a plural of an objects for instance:

> Die Delphine können mit den Menschen in gewisser Weise kommunizieren.
>
> > **Dolphins are able to maintain certain communication with humans**

Now, for the most part, the sentence makes sense to me, but I can't understand why we need the "Die" i.e.

> Delphine können mit den Menschen in gewisser Weise kommunizieren.

Is the definite article really that necessary? I thought the top instance was more formal than the second one (i.e. for colloquial speech) but I wasn't sure.

Comment: I actually think the second one would be used more often, if you take away "den" then it sounds perfect: `Delphine können mit Menschen in gewisser Weise kommunizieren.`

Answer (score 4):

The use of the article depends on the preceding context. In general, no article is used in the plural:

> Delfine können mit Menschen in gewisser Weise kommunizieren.

→ dolphins in general, as a species (same applies to Menschen, no article)

but:

> Die Delfine können mit den Menschen in gewisser Weise kommunizieren.

→ you place extra stress on the dolphins, e.g. after talking about different animals as in the following example:

> Im Meer leben viele Tiere: Fische, Delfine, Robben usw. Die Delfine
>   können mit den Menschen kommunizieren.

meaning that the dolphins are the only ones who can communicate, the others can't.

(In this case you'd place an article before Meschen too. I can't explain why, it just sounds better with the article. Simply Menschen without article is also acceptable.)

Comment: Notice that in these examples, _die_ is actually not an article but a demonstrative pronoun, the form of which only resembles that of the article _die_.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich - I don't think so. It is a demonstrative pronoun in a case like "Im Meer leben viele Delfine. **Die** können mit uns kommunizieren." When _die_ is followed by a noun it's an article. See https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/der_Demonstrativpronomen#Bedeutung2a.

Comment: The assumption that _die_ (also _der_ and _das_) followed by a noun cannot be a demonstrative pronound is wrong! Surprisingly enough, the DUDEN page lists several counter examples of your assumption, e.g., the first one at 1.a. is: _der Mann war es_. I admit that in your examples _die_ can be either an article or a demonstrative pronoun; but that depends on its function, and not on whether it is followed by a noun.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich right, but this has nothing to do with the case in question here. In 1a, the _Der_ is stressed: It was this man (not the other). Der can be substituted by _dieser_ here: welcher Mann? --> dieser bzw. der.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way as the definite article in plurals is not always necessary in English it is also not necessary in German:

Your second example would be used more often, and if you take away "den" then it sounds perfect:

> Delphine können mit Menschen in gewisser Weise kommunizieren.

exceptions exist: e.g. in this case the sentence sounds better with the definite article

> Die Mannschaften haben ein gutes Spiel geliefert

but then in English you would use the article as well: `the squads played a good game`

Comment: of course you need the article before Mannschaft as it is singular. This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Stef thanks to point that out, now it sounds good I think